# ddwrt to openwrt; blocking a host name or domain based on mac address

Tags: iptables, openwrt, filter, mac-address

I'm a recent convert from ddwrt to openwrt. On ddwrt, I could use the lines below to block the amz address for my firetv. I tried doing this on openwrt, but I can still access the address.

```
insmod xt_mac 
insmod ipt_mac
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -m mac --mac-source C0:33:5E:0F:6A:D3 -d amzdigital-a.akamaihd.net -j logdrop
```

^^works on **ddwrt**, it is not as consistent as the ip version below. (which works **ALL** the time.)

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -s 192.168.1.131 -d amzdigital-a.akamaihd.net -j logdrop
```

I'm pretty sure it is possible to filter specific addresses or domains by mac, and I'm just missing something. Can someone offer some assistance?